# Drill Up/Down example?

Tags: database, data-warehouse, olap, cube

I need an example of what drill up/down is ( + if it's graphical ) for a better understanding of these operations. I'm new to the whole Data Warehouse subject so high level explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with Pivot tables in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is usually used in reporting. **[Here is a nice article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1329)** with screenshots.

Comment: This was too low level and too specific of an example for me to grasp. Something more generic would be better I think.